# What is extropy?

Tags: entropy, information-theory, definition, kullback-leibler, heterogeneity

While searching for the answer to a statistics problem, I came across the term *extropy*, which was - and to a large extent still is - unfamiliar to me. A quick google search revealed that it is the "complementary dual of entropy", but didn't reveal much else. A search on google scholar seems to trace it back to this paper:

> Frank Lad. Giuseppe Sanfilippo. Gianna Agrò. "Extropy: Complementary Dual of Entropy." Statist. Sci. 30 (1) 40 - 58, February 2015. https://doi.org/10.1214/14-STS430

I read the abstract but didn't quite understand it. Could somebody explain to me what *extropy* is and what it is meant to be used for?

Comment: Did you read the paper? Seems like the authors define this term there, so unlikely there’s a better resource. If you did, what exactly you don't understand from it?

Comment: @Tim I tried, yes; though I may not have the correct background for it (unfortunately neither a mathematician nor statistician). One of the things that keep throwing me - maybe the main thing - is that I don't understand what a _complementary dual_ is. I was hoping that someone had a simpler (but perhaps less compact) explanation of extropy, primed with which I could re-read the paper and hopefully make more sense of it.